# How I can find actual using of package?

Tags: libraries

I need to find actual process or dependence on other library in running system for package by name.

How I can realize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Aptitude.

Aptitude is a TUI (Terminal User Interface) application managing program. It runs in a terminal but it is pretty intuitive to use anyways.

Install aptitude by using:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

in a terminal. 

Run aptitude with:

```
aptitude
```

You can open up a terminal with CTRL+ALT+T

After you are in aptitude, you can use the `/` key to search for a package. If it isn't found the first time you search for it, you can use the `/` key and search for it again to find the next match.

After you have found the package that you want info on, press the `enter` key. That will bring up info on a package. You can navigate through it by using the up and down arrow keys.